# gzip files by month of its creation

Tags: unix, gzip

I have a mailbox, that is used for logging purposes, with 190k messages. I want to gzip messages in it's directory that is located in:

/home/account/mail/domain/mailarchive/cur

so that all files (e-mail messages) that are older than certain date (1 July) are gziped, but one gzip file should be created for each month.

so the outcome should be something like that:

```
mailarchive-201512.gzip
mailarchive-201601.gzip
mailarchive-201602.gzip
...
mailarchive-201607.gzip
```

which unix command can I use to achieve that?

Comment: What format is the mailbox in ? Is every message in a separate file, or is there some mbox format where a bunch of messages are stored in a single file?

Comment: What about getting YYYYMM of each file -> dumping into respected folder -> Creating gzip for the same?

Comment: How is the creation date stored? (Note that most Unix filesystems do not record creation dates, just modification, last access, and last inode change.)

Comment: @vielmetti each message is in a separate file

Comment: @KeithThompson I guess modification date will work

Comment: Or, since these are e-mail messages, you might look at the headers in the message. It depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: The old Rand MH mailer has a command `pick` documented here http://rand-mh.sourceforge.net/book/mh/finpic.html that would be ideal for your purposes, but I don't think I can recommend installing it just to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, so I'm sharing the solution I found.

Go to the directory containing the files and then use:

```
find -type f -printf 'zip mailarchive-%TY%Tm.zip %f\n' | sh
```

This will zip **all files** in the directory in different zip files according to the modified year and month. It will keep the original files.
If you dont't want to keep the uncompressed files use:

```
find -type f -printf 'zip mailarchive-%TY%Tm.zip %f; rm %f\n' | sh
```